# Express rendering html as view engine is giving an error of function of callback is required

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a new express project with html as engine where it requires `hbs`.

Here is the engine setup:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views')));
```

I am getting an error of:

> Error Callback function required

Here is a screen shot of it:

[image]

And here is my full `app.js` script:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemon = require('nodemon');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views')));
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my npm version:

`5.5.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs) says to use `app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);`